# 20.04 GUI/Desktop - Icons jumping glitch on Dell Latitude E7470

Tags: 20.04, dell, icons

I tried to search and I couldn't find an exact match, might be my wording.

Recently installed 20.04 on Dell Latitude E7470.

When I delete an icon on my desktop, it's like the icons "refresh" themselves and them change order..but "order" / "rearrange desktop" isn't even an option anymore like 18.

There's been some other weird stuff in that opening a new browser in Chrome will open behind other windows, it's just not how it used to be on 18.

Is this just how it is, or have others had weird experiences like that and there are certain updates or drivers I need to change?

Comment: By 18 do you mean 18.04? There is no 18.

Comment: Exactly. Just used short-hand, couldn't remember the exact version for the LTS